# Understanding async/await - why ConfigureAwait(false) and GetAwaiter().GetResult() caused deadlock but wrapped inside Task doesn't cause deadlock

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

I need to understand more about why async/await causes deadlock. As far as I know, using `ConfigureAwait(false)` will marshall back the operation to the original `SynchronizationContext`. I tried the following but it caused a deadlock:

```
protected async Task<WResult<T>> GetAsync<T>(string requestUri, ReqModel model = null)
{
    //...
    //...
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(
        "https://somewebsite.com/api/account/" + requestUri);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
    //...
    //...
    return res;   //deadlock occurs here
}

public async Task<WResult<MId>> VerifyTokenAsync()
{
    return await GetAsync<MId>("tokens").ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public WResult<MId> VerifyToken()
{
    return VerifyTokenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

However, if I wrap it around Task, it works fine.

```
protected async Task<WResult<T>> GetAsync<T>(string requestUri, ReqModel model = null)
{
    //...
    //...
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(
        "https://somewebsite.com/api/account/" + requestUri);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);
    //...
    //...
    return res;
}

public async Task<WResult<MId>> VerifyTokenAsync()
{
    return await GetAsync<MId>("tokens");
}

public WResult<MId> VerifyToken()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => VerifyTokenAsync().Result).Result;
}
```

The `VerifyToken()` is called in ASP.NET MVC controller. I want to understand why using `ConfigureAwait(false)` caused the deadlock.

Thanks...

**Edit**: here is the full function of GetAsync()

```
protected async Task<WResult<T>> GetAsync<T>(string requestUri, ReqModel model = null)
{
    if (model != null) requestUri += model.ToQueryString().ToLower();
    
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(
        "https://somewebsite.com/api/account/" + requestUri);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    string body = response?.Content?.Headers?.ContentLength > 0 ?
        await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) : "";

    WResult<T> res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WResult<T>>(body);
    res.HttpBody = body;
    res.HttpStatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
    return res;   //deadlock occurs here
}
```

Comment: None of the two snippets should deadlock. Are you sure that the deadlock in the first snippet is not caused by code that you have omitted, and replaced with `...`?

Comment: Hi @TheodorZoulias, I have included the all codes that I used `...`. When stepping into code, it stuck on `return res;`

Comment: My guess was that there was some other `await` inside the `GetAsync`, that was not configured with `ConfigureAwait(false)`. I can see now that this is not the case. I am surprised by this deadlock, it shouldn't happen, and I can't think of any explanation. Does your program deadlock also when you run it as standalone application, without the VS debugger attached?

Comment: Hi @TheodorZoulias, when I run through a console application, it works fine. I used a console application to test each function. All of them work ok. For a quick workaround, I am using `Task.Factory.StartNew(...).Result;` to overcome this problem in MVC.NET controller. But I would like to understand why it caused deadlock.

Comment: I am asking about running the ASP.NET application without the debugger attached, not as a console application. The debugger sometimes messes things up, and people end up debugging the debugger instead of debugging their programs.

Comment: As a side-note the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` before the `.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` is redundant. The `ConfigureAwait` has no effect when there is no `await`.

Comment: Have a read https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#warning-deadlocks? Short answer: Just don't do it. Use async all the way or switch to ASP core.

Comment: @Oliver the [link](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#warning-deadlocks) that you posted contains this note: *"ASP.NET Core does not have a `SynchronizationContext` and is not prone to the deadlock problem."* If I am not mistaken that OP's application is ASP.NET Core, so they shouldn't experience deadlocks either going async all the way or half way.

Comment: As a side-note the `return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => VerifyTokenAsync().Result).Result;` blocks two threads. At least do `return Task.Run(() => VerifyTokenAsync()).Result;` to block just one thread.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: The OP used the Tag asp.net-mvc-4 which is NOT core. So could probably be the problem. Or where did you found the hint in the question that the app is Core and not legacy .Net?

Comment: Yes, the application is not ASP.NET core. It is a legacy application, I can't switch to ASP.NET core. Plus, my boss will never agree with it. Right now, we have a workaround which is wrapping inside Task. The purpose of the question is that I want to understand why `ConfigureAwait(false)` caused deadlock. I thought `ConfigureAwait(false)` will not marshal the operation back to the SynchronizationContext. My intention is to learn more (and understand more about `ConfigureAwait(false)`).

Comment: @Oliver you are right, it's not Core. I was not familiar with the ASP.NET MVC and its versions.

Comment: Can you upload a full project that reproduces this behavior to GitHub? I have heard about `GetAsync` implementations with this issue on mobile, and I'd love to see what exact version of `HttpClient` you're using.